# socket io nodejs use variable from one socket listener to another socket listener?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

```
var x ="apple";

socket.on('fruits',function(data){
  var x = data;  //var x is orange here
});

console.log(x); /// but var x is still apple here.....


socket.on('DatatoServer',function(  
   socket.in(x).emit('receivedData', data); ///I want this x to be orange
});
```

how do I make that var x to become global variable?

or is there a way I can use that orange var x in my second socket.on listener above?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `var` keyword you are actually declaring a new variable x within the scope of your callback.

To reference `x` in the global scope, remove the `var` and set it directly.

Also, the fact that it's a callback might change the global scope, using an arrow function for your callback could resolve this.

```
socket.on('fruits', (data) => { 
    x = data; //var x is orange here
 });
```

Comment: I tried removing var,  so it becomes x ="apple";   also tried x ="data";   still getting apple

Comment: You would need To remove the other var, inside the callback

Comment: my third line of code, I tried x = "data" , still getting apple for 5th and 7th line of code

Comment: See my edits, and review the scoping rules in the linked answer